# python print iteratively from two lists

Tags: python-3.x

Let's cut to the chase:

I want to write an iterative print statement, so that given

```
names = ["val_loss","accuracy","f2_loss"] 
values= [0.2454431134, 0.832532234, 0.982762611]
```

the script should print so that numbers are round off to **6 decimal places**, and the list is **dynamically iterated on.**

Example:

```
val_loss: 0.245443, accuracy: 0.832532, f2_loss: 0.982762
```

The kind of iterator I want is something like:

```
strr = [names[i],":",values[i] for i in range(len(metrics)]
```

but of course the above doesn't work because I'm not a python wiz. and cannot always write a non-trivial list iterator.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use zip and fancy formatting ;)

```
strs = []
for (name, value) in zip(names, values):    
    strs.append("{}:{:.6f}".format(name, value))

print(', '.join(strs))
```

Or, as a fancy 1-liner...

```
print(', '.join(("{}:{:.6f}".format(n, v) for (n, v) in zip(names, values))))
```

**Explanation**

In Python2, use `itertools.izip` instead of zip, in Python3, use zip. Zip allows you to lazily merge N-iterables and create tuples of N-length, so `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])` effectively becomes `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`. zip is a great tool for any Python programmer.

As for the formatting piece, you should  read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). A quick explanation is `f` stands for floating pointer numbers, `{}` is a replacement group, and `:.6f` means a float with a max of 6 decimals.

Answer (score -2):

you could do like this:-
strr = [name + ":" + str(value) + ","  for name in  names for value in values]

Comment: This calculates the cartesian product of the two lists, and doesn't solve the rounding issue (the OP wanted 6 decimal places). Definitely not what was desired.